# module.exports not available on dependency (import)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

Recently upgraded a project to Gatsby 3 whose dependency is Webpack 5. In one of the .tsx classes, an import to the library **countdown** is done. The **import** returns an empty object every time, {}.

Looking at the code from "countdown" library I see they export the module like this:

```
/*global window */
var module;

var countdown = (
    
function(module) {
    'use strict';
    ...
    if (module && module.exports) {
        module.exports = countdown;

    } else if (typeof window.define === 'function' && typeof window.define.amd !== 'undefined') {
        window.define('countdown', [], function() {
            return countdown;
        });
    }
    return countdown;
})(module);
```

Using **console.log** inside the library I see that **module.exports** is actually undefined, it seems that  **var module;** is overriding whatever value Node makes available when the **import** is called. To test the hypothesis out I removed the **var module;** and removed it as an argument to the function, and everything worked. Of course, that's not the answer to my problem since this is a dependency library, I have no right to touch its code.

I can't figure out what the upgrade to Webpack 5 could have broken to not make **module.exports** available to **countdown.js** even though they declare the variable.

I looked at [webpack updates](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/) and tried to tell it to use commonjs or import-loader on countdown.js and pass it "module" (different test cases have been commented out):

```
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\countdown.js?$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          // loader: "imports-loader",
          // options: {
          //   syntax: "default",
          //   type: "commonjs"
          // },
          // use: [
          //   {
          //     loader: "imports-loader",
          //     options: {
          //       thisArg: "module"
          //     },
          //   },
          // ],
        },
      ],
    }
```

None of that work. I can't quite figure out what changed in Webpack 5 to cause countdown's way of exporting the library to break.

Any ideas?

To make it clear: the library **countdown** is not mine, and when using previous webpack version it worked great when importing and using it.

Comment: That does not solve your problem but `Of course, that's not the answer to my problem since this is a dependency library, I have no right to touch its code.` that's not true you could always create an issue and/or pull-request for opensource projects.

Comment: webpack 5 seems to treat `module` in a different way now. More like a keyword than a global variable. So having `var module` will shadow the _"global"_ `module`. But I could find anything giving more insights on that.

Comment: You are right on that @t.niese , I could make a pull request.

Comment: I checked that `countdownjs` library while investigating the problem and it does not seem to be maintained. The last commit was 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the package has been updated but version update hasn't been propagated. There's a [request](https://github.com/mckamey/countdownjs/issues/39) soliciting that.

In the meantime a colleague had a solution, thought I'd share it here in case anyone can use it until version is updated. In summary it modifies the script from the library after installation is done, it removes the declared global variable that is overriding the one that Node is supposed to pass.

In a file called **yarn-postinstall.js** (or whatever you please):

```
fixCountdownLib();

function fixCountdownLib() {
  const fs = require("fs");

  const countdownLibPath = __dirname + "/node_modules/countdown/countdown.js";
  const countdownLibCode = fs.readFileSync(countdownLibPath).toString();

  const fixedCountdownLibCode = countdownLibCode.replace("var module;", "");

  fs.writeFileSync(countdownLibPath, fixedCountdownLibCode);
}
```

Then update package.json scripts to point to that file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node yarn-postinstall.js"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

The `module` variable isn't an `object`, and doesn't have a property `exports`.

Changing `var module;` to `var module = {exports: {}}` should work. But I'm not sure you should be checking for `module.exports`, since it's supposed to be `undefined` anyways, I guess?

Comment: The library where there's a defined "var module" is not mine, I can't edit it. When using webpack 4 it worked fine, it's the update that's made it  not work.

Comment: @Chayemor it may be a bug with webpack.